# How to use CKEditor as an NPM module built with webpack or similar

Tags: ckeditor

How can I use CKEditor from npm with webpack?

Ideally I want `npm install ckeditor --save` then `var CK = require('ckeditor');` without any global namespace pollution.

Comment: Is there any success with it?

Comment: Presumably this question is not specific to webpack, but rather "How can I use ckeditor as an ES6 module" (or CommonJS module.) I'd like to know the same thing.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

CKEditor was published on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor).

Now you can use exactly the commands you want.

### Install

```
npm install ckeditor --save-dev
```

### Inject

```
var CK = require('ckeditor');
```

Comment: I get the error: `TypeError: CK.replace is not a function`

Comment: Could you post a question giving more details?

Answer (score 13):

**The problem**

As far as I can tell it isn't currently possible to load CKEDITOR directly into webpack as a chunck without getting some errors, especially when starting to load additional plugins. One of the reasons for this seems to be that ckeditor does it's own async requests at runtime causing various things to break in nearly all of the implementations I have tried.

**The solution**

Use scriptjs to load it as an external library.

```
npm install scriptjs --save
```

Now in your code you can call it like so:

```
var $s = require('scriptjs');
$s('./vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js', function(){
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
});
```

**Please Note.**

This will not work on the uncompressed source because the ckeditor functions are not directly in the ckeditor.js file. This will cause the rest of your logic to run before the CKEDITOR object is fully constructed due to unfinished network requests.

If you wish to modify the source code of CKEDITOR clone https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev and run it's build script to get a working customised version.

It looks like CKEditor is embracing ES6 in version 5 and I suspect they will have webpack support in this version but who knows how long it will be in development before it is released.

If there is a better way of doing this, please let me know.

Comment: I am a little confused on how to implement this solution in my situation. I guess I am wondering why you added --save-dev. I mean, even in prod, after webpack has produced the chunked assets, wouldn't I need scriptjs to fetch ckeditor async?

Comment: I have successfully added this to my webpack project using your solution above. Still wondering why you are only --save-dev and not just --save, seems like you would need scriptjs in prod as well....

Comment: This does work, thanks. Its a pity that all these formerly great softwares are stuck in the dinosaur days, using ancient methodologies like forcing us to stuff their <scripts> in <head> tags - completely defeating the point of using javascript frameworks like Angular2 and module bundlers like Webpack. Hopefully they sort this out in the next version.

Answer (score 7):

It is posible to use CKEditor with Webpack, it requires that you bundle with Webpack the CKEditor files will be loading from the browser, like plugins and language files.

It is done with the [`require.context()`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context) api.

Create your own Webpack module and name it **ckeditor_loader** with the following files:

```js
/* index.js */

import './loader.js'
import 'ckeditor/ckeditor'

// You can replace this with you own init script, e.g.:
// - jQuery(document).ready()
window.onload = function () {
  window.CKEDITOR.replaceAll()
}
```

```js
/* loader.js */

window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = `/node_modules/ckeditor/` # This should beging with your `output.publicPath` Webpack option. 

// Load your custom config.js file for CKEditor.
require(`!file-loader?context=${__dirname}&outputPath=node_modules/ckeditor/&name=[path][name].[ext]!./config.js`)

// Load files from ckeditor.
require.context(
  '!file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]!ckeditor/',
  true,
  /.*/
)
```

```js
/* config.js */

window.CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
  // Define changes to default configuration here.
  // For complete reference see:
  // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config
}
```

Now make sure your module is loaded:

```js
// Include in one of the javascript files that webpack
// is already processing. Probably index.js or app.js:
import 'ckeditor_loader'
```

This is a very basic implementation. I wrote a more extensive tutorial, which allows for faster compilation times and more customization options:
[How to use CKEditor 4 with Webpack](https://www.fomfus.com/articles/how-to-use-ckeditor-4-with-webpack)

Comment: Perhaps summarise the contents of that blog post? It will help future visitors if the blog dies for any reason, leaving behind this answer to be a bit of a shell/lacking detail?

Comment: Great tutorial. Please update your answer, so I can up-vote it.

Comment: Answer updated with more context and an quick overview of the solution.

Comment: could you please explain `Include somewhere in your webpack loader file:`

Comment: @AlexeySh. explained ;)

Answer (score 5):

#### Install

```
npm install ckeditor --save
```

#### Load

```
require('ckeditor');
```

After loading chkeditor becomes available as global variable `CKEDITOR`

#### Replace

```
CKEDITOR.replace('elementId');
```

#### Issues

The editor loads it's own required CSS/JS assets, likely these cannot be found. You can refer to the CDN version for these resources or you can copy the CKeditor directory to an public reachable folder. Define the URL of the public reachable resources with `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH`.

```
window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH    = '//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/full-all/';
```

Note: Define `window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` before your import statement!

Comment: I'm getting errors `Unexpected token <`, `Unexpected token <`,  `Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined`

Comment: Do you define the basepath before your import statement?

Answer (score 1):

CK Editor 5 can be easily used with webpack: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/quick-start.html

Although it should be noted that as of Feb 2018 it is still in alpha2: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5#packages

I was able to get started with Rails and webpacker by using the following:

```
yarn add \
    css-loader  \
    node-sass \
    raw-loader \
    sass-loader \
    style-loader

yarn add \
    @ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic \
    @ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials \
    @ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph \
    @ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles
```

In the code I copied directly from the quick start guide:

```
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor'
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials'
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph'
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold'
import Italic from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic'

const element = document.getElementById('editor')

ClassicEditor.create(element, {
  plugins: [Essentials, Paragraph, Bold, Italic],
  toolbar: ['bold', 'italic']
})
.then(editor => {
  console.log('Editor was initialized', editor)
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error.stack)
})
```

Finally I had to add a loader for ckeditor svg icons as per the quick start guide. I used the webpacker reference here for that https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md#react-svg-loader

```
// config/webpacker/environment.js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

environment.loaders.insert('svg', {
  test: /ckeditor5-[^/]+\/theme\/icons\/[^/]+\.svg$/,
  use: 'raw-loader'
}, { after: 'file' })

const fileLoader = environment.loaders.get('file')
fileLoader.exclude = /ckeditor5-[^/]+\/theme\/icons\/[^/]+\.(svg)$/i

module.exports = environment
```

Comment: Paul, I'm having issues with importing ClassicEditor - it says ClassicEditor is undefined. I'm using webpacker with Rails 6.1. Thoughts?