# Angular CLI and ckeditor?

Tags: webpack, ckeditor, angular-cli

I'm attempting to move over to Angular CLI to I can minimize and bundle my application, so that distribution filesize is shrunk considerably.

The application uses ckeditor. (Not ng-ckeditor, just the normal ckeditor.) I just ran across [this discussion](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/issues/41#issuecomment-250254364), which indicates that ckeditor cannot be included in a webpack bundle.

Does this mean I cannot use Angular CLI? Or is there a way to reference an un-minimized, un-bundled ckeditor from a WebPack bundled (via ng-CLI) application?

Would I put ckeditor in my 'assets' folder? Or perhaps instead put it directly into the 'dist' folder, and reference it directly from index.html? But 'dist' gets rebuild every build... how would I automate copying the ckeditor folder in there, via Angular CLI?

Comment: you can include any external JS file in `.angular-cli.json` in the `scripts` section. What angular-cli will do, is find all those JS files in `scripts` section concat and minify them and produce a file which will be in `dist` folder and referenced in index.html

Comment: Right. However, the issue with ckeditor is that it attempts to load its own plug-ins, and this breaks when it is 'bundled' in this way. I did find a solution however... I'll share it later.

Comment: are you including the ES module? you should be including the vanilla compiled JS code instead. The `scripts` will literally include the JS file you point it, not try and follow it's `import` statements like a bundler would. Anyway, I'm glad you found a solution

Comment: This might explain the issue better (see answer by Dieter Gribnitz): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703324/how-to-use-ckeditor-as-an-npm-module-built-with-webpack-or-similar

Comment: Would you please share the solution?